# How to trigger onchange event on html elements inside jslt foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, jsp-tags

I have a Jsp pages edit student registered data. All the details are
fetched using jslt foreach. But the problem is i cannot perform any
javascript event inside foreach loop on any html input elements like
check box because all this data is fetched inside foreach loop.

I think javascript is not working because of foreach scope.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: And along with that example provide a proper explanation of what you are trying to accomplish